# Intellij java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet when running Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

I am trying to figure out how to get a Java Enterprise Web Application with servlets running and I was following the tutorial here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J212XSlZfDY

I am using Tomcat server 10.0.21 and Intellij 11.0.14.1

I get one simple index.jsp running and when I try to submit inputs, the server fails to respond, seemingly because the HttpServlet class is not found, although the import works.

Servlet code:

```
package com.example.foodstuffz;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import java.io.IOException;


@WebServlet("/foodate")
public class FoodStuffzServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public FoodStuffzServlet() {};

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a"));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));

        int sum = a+b;

        response.getWriter().println(sum);
    }
}
```

index.jsp code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foodstuffz</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h1><%= "Hello World!" %></h1>
            <br/>
            <form action="foodate" method="post">
                <p>Input Number <input type="number" name="a" required /></p>
                <p>Input Number <input type="number" name="b" required /></p>
                <p>Input Number <input type="submit" value="RUN" /></p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FoodStuffzServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.foodstuffz.FoodStuffzServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FoodStuffzServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foodate</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is the error I am getting in the browser:

```
Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [com.example.foodstuffz.FoodStuffzServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.example.foodstuffz.FoodStuffzServlet]

Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
```

I did not include the entire error message, just the exceptions mentioned. If anything else is needed please let me know. Can anyone figure out what I am missing? Thank you very much!

Comment: Use Tomcat 9, Tomcat 10 is not a Java Servlet Container but a Jakarta Servlet Container and uses the `jakarta.servlet` namespace not the `javax.servlet` one. So if you have code that still uses the old servlet API use anything before Tomcat 10, else use Tomcat 10.